# How to define setings for individual files and sync them using git along with the file?

Tags: vim

I am trying to create file specific settings in vim, so like if I open "file1", I want to run ":syntax off, :show number", then when I open "file2" I want to run some different commands. So like this there are many files for which I want to define some rules. I dont want to target the files using some regex or anything. I want settings for individual files. So I think what I can do is create a settings file for each file in the same directory as the file. So when I sync the repo with git the settings file aslo get synced.

I have achieved fine-tune settings using autcmd, by putting this in .vimrc

```
autocmd BufReadPre,FileReadPre file1 :syntax off
```

But I dont want to clutter my .vimrc file with all the file settings. Also I will have to sync the vimrc file separate from the project folder.

So I read this answer in which they told me to do this to source a .vimrc in your current project directory from the project root folder

```
:set exrc
```

I didn't get how to do that, do I have to run that every time I open a file?

Can I achieve that without installing any extra plugin?

Comment: Do you know "modeline"? See `:help modeline`. Assuming `#` starts a comment, you could add `# vim:syntax=:number:`.

Answer (score 0):

#### exrc

The [`:help 'exrc'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27exrc%27) option just lets Vim source its configuration from the current directory instead of `~/.vimrc`. For that to work, you need to open all project files from the (Git) root directory. Also, because the initialization only runs once on Vim launch, you still need to define `:autocmd BufRead` (assuming you open more than one file per Vim session), but at least you now have them within the project, not globally outside.

#### localrc plugins

A *localrc* plugin improves on this by sourcing the (project-, or even directory-scoped) configuration for *every* file that is opened within the directory tree. Instead of `:autocmd`, you then need a conditional matching the current filename (`if expand('%:t') == 'file1' ...`).

There are several such plugins; I can recommend the [localrc plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393) (especially with [my own enhancements](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-localrc/tree/enhancements)), which even allows local filetype-specific configuration.

#### modeline (plugins)

A localrc plugin works well if you have the same configuration for (few) sets of files. If I understand you correctly, you rather have distinct commands for separate files, and little duplication. For that, [`:help modeline`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#modeline) would be great (if it's fine to add a comment to the files, that is). Unfortunately (for security reasons), Vim only allows to set *options* (e.g. `'syntax'` or `'textwidth'`); you cannot execute arbitrary commands. For your example commands (`:syntax off`, `:set number`), that would work, though:

```
/* vim: syntax= number */
```

#### modeline with compound filetype

If you need a bulked-up modeline that can also execute any Vim command, or to de-duplicate a set of settings for more than one particular file, you can define a custom filetype and set this as a *compound filetype* in the modeline, e.g.

```
# vim: set ft=c.kAndRstyle
```

and then have the settings in `~/.vim/ftplugin/kAndRstyle.vim`. The only downside here is that you have to explicitly mention the original syntax in the modeline as well.

#### modeline plugins

Some plugins (among them my [ModelineCommands plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5767); some alternatives are listed on its plugin page) extend modeline syntax to allow setting Vim variables or even execute arbitrary Vim commands, directly within the modeline itself.

#### companion Vimscript

For a true one-to-one mapping, you can automatically source a Vimscript file that lies next to the opened file via the following hook:

```
" Automatically source an eponymous %:r.vim or %.vim if it exists, as a
" bulked-up modeline and to provide file-specific customizations.
function! s:AutoSource()
    let l:testedScripts = [expand('<afile>') . '.vim']
    if expand('<afile>:e') !=# 'vim'    " Don't source the edited Vimscript file itself.
        call add(l:testedScripts, expand('<afile>:r') . '.vim')
    endif

    for l:filespec in l:testedScripts
        if filereadable(l:filespec)
            try
                execute 'source' fnameescape(l:filespec)
            catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:/
                echomsg v:exception
            endtry
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
augroup AutoSource
    autocmd! BufNewFile,BufRead * nested call <SID>AutoSource()
augroup END
```